# MySQL mixing AND's and OR's, parenthesis not helping

Tags: mysql

For some reason this query does not produce the correct results, can anyone see if I am making a simple mistake. If worst comes to worse I will seperate it into two querys and use my app engine to merge the results, but that is slow and dirty and I would love to keep this is one query.

```
SELECT *
FROM `chat_messages` 
WHERE
(
(`from` = :me AND `to` = :them AND `from_clear` = FALSE) OR 
(`from` = :them AND `to` = :me AND `to_clear` = FALSE)
) 
ORDER BY `time` ASC;
```

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE `chat_messages` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `to` varchar(16) NOT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `message` text NOT NULL,
  `read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `from_clear` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `to_clear` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `from` (`from`),
  KEY `to` (`to`),
  KEY `time` (`time`),
  KEY `read` (`read`),
  KEY `from_clear` (`from_clear`),
  KEY `to_clear` (`to_clear`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Exactly what do you want to do with the above query?

Comment: First you do not need the phirst paranthese after `WHERE` and the latest one, before `ORDER BY`. Second, what it means: "does not produce correct results"? Can you detail?

Comment: In order to help you out, you should let us know what results you are expecting, and what results you are actually getting. It appears that the query will find messages from me to them with `from_clear` false, or messages from them to me with `to_clear` false. Is that actually what you are trying to do? What isn't working?

Comment: Also, what library are you using to bind values to `:me` and `:them`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the error, you can't really get the proper answer here. But as was noted in one of the comments, your bind method may be the cause. This is a wild guess, but could it be that you are not binding correctly, or don't have enough values?

Try hardcoding the values in your statement. I bet it works, and then you can deal with the binding issues. Sometimes you have to have 2 variables rather than one being named twice, but it depends.  In other words, you might have to try:

```
(`from` = :me_1 AND `to` = :them_1 AND `from_clear` = FALSE) OR 
(`from` = :them_2 AND `to` = :me_2 AND `to_clear` = FALSE)
```

Comment: I am using the PDO library to do the binding. What I was trying to do was get all the messages between two users which have not been cleared yet. The sql was not properly returning the list of messages, when one cleared their list it would screw up both of their lists. MJB solution worked, it must be an issue with the multiple binds.